# Why does the '{' in my if statement cause an error? PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a login system for my users. As usual, I'm splicing together code that I find online and trying to analyze how it works.

The idea is that I have a username and password field to be filled out and when they submit, the function defined is activated. Here is my code; it's only one page:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['logged in']){ //<-- this '{' is causing an error, because it is apparently "unexpected"
    header(Location:"http://terrythetutor.com/passwordprotectedpage.php");
    }
    if(isset($submit)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
$con = mysqli_connect("*?*?*?*?**?*??*?*?*","**********","??????????","??????");    
$S_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$S_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutors WHERE username = ' . $S_username . ' AND password = ' . $S_password . ' LIMIT 1" ;
$check = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$check_again = mysql_num_rows($check);

    if($check_again) == 1 {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged in'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $S_username;
    }
    else {
    echo "Your username and password combination was not recognised. Please try again."
    }

?>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
    <?php include_once 'googleanalytics.php'; ?>
<body>
<a href="http://terrythetutor.com">
    <div class="banner"> </div>
</a>
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
<h1 align="center">Please login to access restricted files</h1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<div align="center">
<form action = "login.php" method = "post"> //login.php is this page

Username: <input type = "text" name = "username"></br></br>

Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"></br></br>

<input type = "submit" value = "Login" name="submit">

</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

My intent is to have the logged in user be able to access a page that someone who isn't logged in cannot access. A secondary question I have: what code should I put where if I want to have only PART of a page displayed differently for an individual who is logged in?

Thanks everyone. You're always great.

Comment: You will need to move `session_start();` to the top of the page if you wish to use the session variables

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a Q&A forum is not an on-line spell checker (and he's even omitting the error message and line number info).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario had I known it was only syntax, I wouldn't have needed to ask the question. I'm sorry I felt the need to ask people who had experience with a language that I did not. I'm sure when you were learning you needed no advice.

Comment: @user2666324 - If you're learning you still need to follow the site guidelines. We all love Stack Overflow because it has quality contents but we want to fill it with junk—that's pretty selfish, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String/Const mistake:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged in']){
//-----------------------------^
header(Location:"http://terrythetutor.com/passwordprotectedpage.php");
//-----^       ^
}
```

Should be

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged in'])) {
    header("Location:http://terrythetutor.com/passwordprotectedpage.php");
}
```

**If:**

```
if($check_again) == 1 {
```

Should be

```
if ($check_again == 1) {
```

**I found a 4th:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutors WHERE username = ' . $.......
//-----^--------------------------------------^
```

Should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutors WHERE username = " . $.......
```

**I suggest to improve your code style and wipe those syntax errors.**

Comment: Dan, I appreciate your help with this. What do you recommend to be proactive in improving my code style?

Comment: @user2666324 have a look into great projects, how they do write code, and into [code style guides](https://www.google.de/search?q=php+code+style+guide)

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged in']){
```

Should be:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged in'])){
```

Comment: It was that simple? Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice catch. Using a good IDE with code highlighting would help a lot to prevent such silly mistakes :)

Answer (score 2):

`if(isset($_SESSION['logged in']){`

Should be

`if(isset($_SESSION['logged in'])){`

Also you will need to change

`if($check_again) == 1 {`

to

`if($check_again == 1) {`

There are also many other issues that will cause errors in your script but to answer your question, see the above.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris good point, didn't see that far down

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged in']){
header(Location:"http://terrythetutor.com/passwordprotectedpage.php");
}
```

should be

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged in'])){
header(Location:"http://terrythetutor.com/passwordprotectedpage.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged in']))
                               ^--^
```

You missed the closing bracket